# Display JSON string Data in HTML Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I get the following JSON String from server as response
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oogFA.png)
Here is my Jquery Code

```
function loadCategories() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Services/ControllerService.asmx/Get",
            data: {},
            cache: false,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                var jsonArray = JSON.parse(result.d);

                alert(jsonArray);




            }, error: function (msg) {
                alert('Error : while executing the outlets : ' + msg.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
```

The alert shows the JSON String Correctly. Now i want to map this response to an html table showing columns "a" and "b"

```
  a        -             b
```

hasOtherInfo        Undergratuate_in_Computing_Faculty

How can i do that ??

Comment: can post the actual response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. loop through the JSON data.
2. get the a and b value
3. write a function that takes care of splitting the value present in   results.a.bindings.value & results.b.bindings.value based on the / and #
4. display the same in your html table
   5(optional). use a jquery table plugin to display your results for a feel good look

Comment: Can you give an example

Comment: can you use pastebin to paste your json returned data and share the link?
http://pastebin.com/index.php
meanwhile you can look at the solution given by user6367045...

you need to add the split functionality in there

Answer (score 0):

You have some plugin that can achieve that:

- [dynatable](https://www.dynatable.com/)
- [Json-to-HTML-Table](https://github.com/afshinm/Json-to-HTML-Table)

Answer (score 0):

As inspecting from your json data you can do this:

```
var tr="";
$.each(jsonArray.results.bindings, function(i,v)
    {
        var td="";
        $.each(v, function(r,s)
            {
                td+='<td>'+s.type+'</td>';
            });

        tr+= '<tr>'+td+'</tr>';

    });
$("yourTableName").find("tbody").html("").html(tr);
```